# Multiple C Source Files in CLion

Tags: c, clion

In a CLion project, I have two C-language source files, "main.c" and "list.c".

The source file "main.c" has this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The source file "list.c" has this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printFoo() {
    printf("I want Krabby Patties!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now how do I call `printFoo()` from the `main()` function? I know I cannot do an `include<list.c>` in main.c since that will cause a multiple definitions error.

Comment: Look up header files in your C book.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure you can do exactly that, except that it would be `#include "list.c"`.  But Stephen is right; learn how to use header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLion uses CMake for organizing and building project.

`CMakeLists.txt` contains instructions for building.

Command `add_executable(program main.c list.c)` creates executable with files `main.c` and `list.c`. Add all source files to it. You can add headers, but it isn't necessary.

Header files contain definitions of functions and other things, source files for realization, but you can merge them.

---

main.c

```
#include "list.h"

int main() {
    printFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

list.h

```
#pragma once
int printFoo();
```

list.c

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int printFoo(){
    return printf("I want Krabby Patties!\n");
}
```

`#pragma once` tels compiler to include header file once. If you have more than one include of one file without `#pragma once`, you'll catch an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one header file "list.h"

```
#ifndef __LIST_H__
#define __LIST_H__ 

int printFoo();

#endif
```

Then include it in `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printFoo();
    return 0;
}
```